# Java method is not calling from XSLT for SAP PO

Tags: java, xslt, mapping, sap-pi

Following is my XSLT code for SAP PO interface:

```
<SEGMENT id="test">
    <FIELD>
        <ID>STAT</ID>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="check = 'I0002'">

                <xsl:param name="param1">
                                PTS
                </xsl:param>

                <xsl:param name="param2">
                                PLANT_WHSE
                </xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="param3">
                    <xsl:value-of select="P002" />
                </xsl:param>


                <xsl:variable name="status">
                    <xsl:value-of
                                    select="javamap:JAVA_METHOD($param1,$param2,$param3,$inputparam)" />
                </xsl:variable>


                <VALUE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($status)"/>
                </VALUE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <VALUE>CRTD</VALUE>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </FIELD>
</SEGMENT>
```

Getting following error:

```
avax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sap.engine.lib.xsl.xslt.XSLException: -> com.sap.engine.lib.xsl.xpath.XPathException: Could not execute operation on Java Object. -> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sap.engine.lib.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:250)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.AbstractMappingTransformer.transform(AbstractMappingTransformer.java:174)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.XSLTMapping.executeStep(XSLTMapping.java:104)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.Mapping.execute(Mapping.java:60)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingHandler.map(MappingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingHandler.map(MappingHandler.java:54)
        at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.rt.MappingHandlerAdapter.run(MappingHandlerAdapter.java:139)
        at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.exec.ExecuteIfMapCommand.execute(ExecuteIfMapCommand.java:33)
        at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.exec.CommandManager.execute(CommandManager.java:43)
        at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.ServerMapService.execute(ServerMapService.java:40)
        at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.MapServiceBean.execute(MapServiceBean.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor882.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.RequestInvocationContext.proceedFinal(RequestInvocationContext.java:47)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:166)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_StatesTransition.invoke(Interceptors_StatesTransition.java:19)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Resource.invoke(Interceptors_Resource.java:50)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Transaction.doWorkWithAttribute(Interceptors_Transaction.java:37)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Transaction.invoke(Interceptors_Transaction.java:21)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_MethodRetry.invoke(Interceptors_MethodRetry.java:46)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:191)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_StatelessInstanceGetter.invoke(Interceptors_StatelessInstanceGetter.java:23)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_SecurityCheck.invoke(Interceptors_SecurityCheck.java:25)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_ExceptionTracer.invoke(Interceptors_ExceptionTracer.java:17)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultInvocationChainsManager.startChain(DefaultInvocationChainsManager.java:138)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.java:172)
        at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.java:99)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3652.execute(Unknown Source)
```

i think there is issue in XSLT. other methods from JAVA are working fine but getting error for this one.

Comment: Check the documentation of the used XSLT processor and its API for calling into Java how XSLT/Path data types are mapped to Java data types. Also consider to post the signature of that Java method if you want us to help by making an educated guess on how to fix the code. Depending on the Java method it is more likely that using e.g. `<xsl:param name="param2" select="'PLANT_WHSE'"/>` works.

Comment: Nice that you included the stacktrace. It was quite unreadable, however. Please format your stacktrace as code so line breaks and indentation are preserved. This time I did it for you.